# The site is readonly at the farm administrator's request for a specific users

Tags: sharepoint-server

Few users in SharePoint 2013 site gets below status in welcome page

**The site is readonly at the farm administrator's request**

These users have same permission like other users.

How to resolve this error?

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Launch Central Administration
2. Click on Application Management
3. Click on `Configure quotas and locks` under Site Collections
4. Make sure the option `No Locked` is checked
5. Click OK

[image]

You can also use powershell to unlock it as below:

```
Set-SPSite -Identity "Site-Collection-URL" -LockState "Unlock"
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The option No Locked is checked. The problem is this occurs for few users in site collection whereas other users are able access or edit the site.

Comment: Which CU is installed on the 2013 farm ?

Comment: October 2016 CU

Comment: Any recent migration of site collection or update ? Check the disk space as well

Comment: yes site collection was moved from different farm

Comment: Check if enough disk space is available. If there is enough space, run below command:
`$Admin = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPSiteAdministration('http://sitecollectionurl')` and then 
`$Admin.ClearMaintenanceMode()`

Comment: Whether this will restart iis or timer service?

Comment: No it wont restart iis or timer service.